Generate PDF code no longer works. Gives a FATAL_ERROR Internal Salesforce.com Error
I have an invocable apex code which I call in flow to generate a PDF and automatically attached a newly created document. As at last week Friday, the code was working perfectly and generating the PDFs. I have a visualforce template which the apex code uses to generate the PDF.
However, when I tried to test it today, it gives the FATAL_ERROR Internal Salesforce.com Error. From the debug log, the code runs very untill when it enters the get PDF content code block, from line 54. I have attached a redacted version of the code using dummy names for data security sake:
public without sharing class PayslipPDFGenerator {

@InvocableMethod(label='Generate Payslip PDF' description='Generates a PDF payslip and attaches it to the Payslip record')

public static void generatePayslipPDF(List<Payslip__c> payslips) {

    if (payslips == null || payslips.isEmpty()) return;

    // Process payslips in future to avoid governor limits

    generatePayslipsFuture(new List<Id>{payslips[0].Id});

}

@Future(callout=true)

private static void generatePayslipsFuture(List<Id> payslipIds) {

    for (Id payslipId : payslipIds) {

        try {

            generateAndAttachPDF(payslipId);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'Error generating PDF for payslip ' + payslipId + ': ' + e.getMessage());

            System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'Stack trace: ' + e.getStackTraceString());

        }

    }

}

private static void generateAndAttachPDF(Id payslipId) {

    // Query the payslip record with all necessary fields

    Payslip__c payslip = [

        SELECT Id, Name, Employee__r.Name,

               Employee_Designation__c, Payroll_Period__c,

               Payment_Date__c, Attendance__c,

               Staff_ID_Location__c, Basic_Salary__c,

               Transport_Allowance__c, Housing_Allowance__c,

               Leave_Allowance__c, Other_Allowance__c,

               Overtime_Allowance_I__c, Overtime_Allowance_II__c,

               Public_Holidays_Allowance__c, Employer_Pension_Contribution__c,

               Employee_Pension_Contribution__c, Tax_Remittance__c,

               NHF_Contribution__c, Total_Gross_Salary__c,

               Total_Net_Payment__c

        FROM Payslip__c

        WHERE Id = :payslipId

    ];

    // Generate PDF

    PageReference pdf = Page.PayslipPDFTemplate;

    pdf.getParameters().put('id', payslip.Id);

    // Set PDF options

    pdf.setRedirect(true);

    // Create ContentVersion

    ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();

    cv.Title = payslip.Name;

    cv.PathOnClient = payslip.Name + '.pdf';

    cv.IsMajorVersion = true;

    try {

        // Get PDF content

        Blob pdfBlob;

        if (Test.isRunningTest()) {

            pdfBlob = Blob.valueOf('Test PDF Content');

        } else {

            pdfBlob = pdf.getContentAsPDF();

        }

        cv.VersionData = pdfBlob;

        insert cv;

        // Get ContentDocument Id

        Id conDocId = [

            SELECT ContentDocumentId 

            FROM ContentVersion 

            WHERE Id = :cv.Id

        ].ContentDocumentId;

        // Create ContentDocumentLink

        ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();

        cdl.ContentDocumentId = conDocId;

        cdl.LinkedEntityId = payslip.Id;

        cdl.ShareType = 'V';

        cdl.Visibility = 'AllUsers';

        insert cdl;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        String errorMsg = 'Failed to generate payslip PDF: ' + e.getMessage() + 

                        '\nStack trace: ' + e.getStackTraceString();

        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, errorMsg);

        throw new PayslipGenerationException(errorMsg);

    }

}

public class PayslipGenerationException extends Exception {}

}
This is the visual force page template
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<apex:page standardController="Payslip__c" 
       renderAs="pdf" 
       applyHtmlTag="false" 
       showHeader="false" 
       cache="false"
       standardStylesheets="false"
       applyBodyTag="false">
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            @page {
                margin: 20px;
                size: A4;
            }
            .header-image {
                width: 100%;
                max-height: 100px;
                margin-bottom: 40px;
            }
            body {
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 12px;
                padding: 20px;
            }
            .header-table, .earnings-table {
                width: 100%;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }
            .header-table td {
                padding: 5px;
                border: 1px solid #000;
            }
            .earnings-table th, .earnings-table td {
                padding: 5px;
                border: 1px solid #000;
                text-align: left;
            }
            .label {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            .footer {
                margin-top: 30px;
            }
            .amount {
                text-align: right;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.Header)}" 
       styleClass="header-image"/>
        
        <table class="header-table">
            <tr>
                <td class="label">Employee Name</td>
                <td>{!Payslip__c._r.Name}</td>
                <td class="label">Designation</td>
                <td>{!Payslip__c.Designation__c}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">Payroll Period:</td>
                <td>{!Payslip__c.Payroll_Period__c}</td>
                <td class="label">Payment Date</td>
                <td>
                    <apex:outputText value="{0,date,dd/MM/yyyy}">
                        <apex:param value="{!Payslip__c.Payment_Date__c}"/>
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">Attendance:</td>
                <td>{!Payslip__c.Attendance__c}</td>
                <td class="label">Staff ID/Location:</td>
                <td>{!Payslip__c.Staff_ID_Location__c}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        
        <table class="earnings-table">
            <tr>
                <th>Earnings</th>
                <th style="text-align: right;">Amount (&#8358;)</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Basic</td>
                <td class="amount">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                        <apex:param value="{!Payslip__c.Basic_Salary__c}"/>
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Transport Allowance</td>
                <td class="amount">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                        <apex:param value="{!Payslip__c.Transport_Allowance__c}"/>
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Housing Allowance</td>
                <td class="amount">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                        <apex:param value="{!Payslip__c.Housing_Allowance__c}"/>
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Leave Allowance</td>
                <td class="amount">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                        <apex:param value="{!Payslip__c.Leave_Allowance__c}"/>
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Other Allowance</td>
                <td class="amount">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                        <apex:param value="{!Payslip__c.Other_Allowance__c}"/>
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Overtime Allowance I</td>
                <td class="amount">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                        <apex:param value="{!Payslip__c.Overtime_Allowance_I__c}"/>
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Overtime Allowance II</td>
                <td class="amount">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                        <apex:param value="{!Payslip__c.Overtime_Allowance_II__c}"/>
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Public Holiday Allowance</td>
                <td class="amount">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                        <apex:param value="{!Payslip__c.Public_Holidays_Allowance__c}"/>
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Employer Pension Contribution</td>
                <td class="amount">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                        <apex:param value="{!Payslip__c.Employer_Pension_Contribution__c}"/>
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Employee Pension Contribution</td>
                <td class="amount">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                        <apex:param value="{!Payslip__c.Pension_Contribution__c}"/>
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tax Remittance</td>
                <td class="amount">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                        <apex:param value="{!Payslip__c.Tax_Remittance__c}"/>
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>NHF Contribution</td>
                <td class="amount">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                        <apex:param value="{!Payslip__c.NHF_Contribution__c}"/>
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">Total Gross Salary</td>
                <td class="amount">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                        <apex:param value="{!Payslip__c.Total_Gross_Salary__c}"/>
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">Total Net Payment</td>
                <td class="amount">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                        <apex:param value="{!Payslip__c.Total_Net_Payment__c}"/>
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Prepared by:</p>
            <p>O.O. Oluwamese (Mrs.)</p>
            <p><strong>Head, Human Resources</strong></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
</apex:page>

This is how the error appears in the debug log:
VARIABLE SCOPE BEGIN              [56]|pdfBlob|Bloblfalse|false
VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT               [56]|pdfBlob|null
HEAP ALLOCATE                     [57]|Bytes:114
SYSTEM METHOD ENTRY               [1]|Test.Test()
STATEMENT EXECUTE                 [1]|
SYSTEM METHOD EXIT                [1]|Test
METHOD ENTRY                      [57]|System.Test.isRunningTest()
METHOD EXIT                       [57]|System.Test.isRunningTest()
STATEMENT EXECUTE                 [59]|
STATEMENT EXECUTE                 [60]|
FATAL ERROR                       Internal Salesforce.com Error

Normally I do check the permissions (visualforce page access + objects + fields + records sharing) first, and then check if page itself can be opened as PDF in browser with the same data. If all works - then could be that some limit is hit - check if it works for part of data submitted.

Thanks @kurunve, all permissions are good, because I am still working in a test org, so the users are always Admins. Opening the page with record also works. Any idea what limits, because it working just fine last week, with no issues, and nothing changed on the code or flow where it is used.

Are there by any chance second debug log created with more detailed error? Inspired by this - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/170866/pagereference-getcontentaspdf-throws-internal-salesforce-com-error

Hi @kurunve just tried that now, the internal error is gone, but then it throwing funny exceptions on fields that have been properly queried.
12:07:41:482 EXCEPTION_THROWN [64]|flair.PayslipPDFGenerator.PayslipGenerationException: PDF Generation failed: common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Payslip__c.Attendance__c

Well, I am out of ideas so far - in those cases I tend to strip all the code to make empty PDF generateable and then uncomment it one by one to find what causes it. Does issue also occur if you run it from anonymous apex? And not in async-mode (in anonymous apex)?

Another thing to try, add the lightningStyleSheets=false attribute to your <apex:page> tag. Had some failures in PDF generation related to that some time ago (I think while using lightning experience instead of classic).
